# Hiding empty rows when the value in a cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make the following code work. It should automatically check and hide empty rows from Range `C18` to `C30` when a user selects different radio buttons which are linked to cell `c17`. which is a start date, so when a user selects different period i want the code to hide/unhide empty rows.

This is the current code and is not working:

```
 Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c17")) Is Nothing Then    
         Range("C18:C30").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False  
     End If
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information? If you can do an example...

Comment: Are you sure the event is triggered by a linked cell change? AFAIK `_Change` is only triggered by user input

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I LEARN FROM YOUTUBE THOUGH, ANYWAYS CAN U EXPLAIN HOW IT SHOULD BE LINKED,

Comment: basically i have values like following, and when user select a radio button start date changes hence, days months are decreased or increased, leaving empty rows, what i want is when a user changes radio button, empty rows should automaticaly be hided,   START DATE 20/10/2017   END DATE 15/10/2018
Oct-17  11
Nov-17  30
Dec-17  31
Jan-18  31
Feb-18  28
Mar-18  31
Apr-18  30
May-18  31
Jun-18  30
Jul-18  31
Aug-18  31
Sep-18  30
Oct-18  15

Comment: Please do not clarify the problem in the comments but [edit] your original post adding the details to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Worksheet_SelectionChange instead of Worksheet_Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c17")) Is Nothing Then
         Range("C18:C30").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False
     End If
 End Sub
```